# GSON convert a POJO to JsonObject

Tags: java, json

How do I convert a POJO to a GSON JsonObject?

```
class MyPojo {
    String name;
    String id;
}

MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
pojo.name = "Roger";
pojo.id = "1";
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(pojo); // Problem is this returns a string instead of a JsonObject
```

Answer (score 4):

```
JsonObject json = gson.toJsonTree(pojo).getAsJsonObject();
```